# Accessing previous MSMessages from MSConversation

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, imessage-extension, msmessage

If I have sent a few messages in my iMessage app and I want to access previous messages (obviously just my own app-created messages, not just any messages the users have sent in their conversation), is there a way I can do that?

I can access the most previous message with this:

`[self activeConversation].selectedMessage;`

Any way to loop through previous messages that might not have even ever been clicked by the user (so simply storing it in *user defaults* is not an option)

Comment: @Cœur, done! Not sure why I had deleted it in the first place

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do this. Apple considers this to be a security/privacy issue.